# wkhtmltopdf not working (pdfkit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf

I'm having trouble generating a PDF out of a html page.

I'm using PDFkit. I installed also wkhtmltopdf following the installation instructions. In 'usr/local/bin/' there is now a file called 'wkhtmltopdf'

When I run a pdf with PDFkit, it now gives an error:

```
command failed: "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf" "--margin-right" "0.75in" "--page-size" "Letter" "--margin-top" "0.75in" "--margin-bottom" "0.75in" "--encoding" "UTF-8" "--margin-left" "0.75in" "--quiet" "-" "-"
```

Also, when I try to generate a PDF directly it gives an error:

```
wkhtmltopdf --page-size A4--quiet http://localhost/invoices/22 -

'/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: cannot execute binary file'
```

Any idea of what this could be?
This is how the PDFkit config file looks:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
end
```

Comment: When I encountered a similar error it was because the account I was executing under did not have execute permissions on wkhtmltopdf. I wound up doing a `chmod` on it.

Comment: I checked the permissions, but it has all permissions for all users.

Comment: It seems some installation issues. Which version of WKHTMLTOPDF you are using and in which OS?

Comment: I am having a similar problem on mac os x lion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the whole path of executable Like this

The path should look like: C:/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdfwkhtmltopdf.exe

try this it works great

Comment: This is the whole path on mac or linux

Comment: Hi @Piioo i think it is windows path

Answer (score 0):

I've installed wkhtmltopdf on my Mac OSX with homebrew and I'm using the wicked_pdf gem and I was getting similar errors. This might be helpful:

In my rails 3 app I have a file app/config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb that contains

```
# brew install wkhtmltopdf
WickedPdf.config = { :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'} if Rails.env == 'development'
```

The worked for me. So you might wanna try:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = { :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf' }
end
```

Also: see the github project page's installation instructions:

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf